# IntelliJ 12.1.5 with lombok @Slf4j can't build

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

Upgrade to IntelliJ 12.1.5 installed lombok plugin,
but can't build @Slf4j

error message like this

```
java: FileName.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable log
```

Comment: Same story, i had to downgrade to be able to run from Idea.

Answer (score 2):

have your tried to Enable annotation processing ?

go under Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors. and make sure 'Enable annotation processing' is enabled.

Otherwise check your dependencies. if you are using Maven to build your project you should have something similar to this in your pom :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [new build](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114130#comment=27-597719) or wait for 12.1.6